# Execute stored procedure SQL using value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Check my table below:

```
ID  Number01  Number02  Number03
-----------------------------------
1   10        20        4510
2   5         2         545
3   4         4         664
4   10        1         NULL
5   1         4         NULL
```

"Number03" field is a calculated field which is Number01 + Number02. I am using a stored procedure to calculate it. Why I am using a stored procedure? Because I have the interface which made by asp.net.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE _mySP
    (@Number01 decimal(18,0), @Number02 decimal(18,0))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myCOM1 float
    DECLARE @myCOM2 float

    SET @myCOM1 = @Number1 + 500
    SET @myCOM2 = POWER(@Number2, 2) * 10

    INSERT INTO _myTable(Number01, Number02, Number03) 
    VALUES (@Number01, @Number02, @myCOM1 + @myCOM2)
END
```

The question is, how can I execute the stored procedure without entering the value one by one? Because the value is already in the table. I want to update all the null value on "Number03" field. Also any idea how execute my question using CURSOR?

EDIT: It seems that my previous question is too simple. So I make it complex a little bit.

Comment: Just select from _myTable in the stored procedure?

Comment: Mabey with an update Statement: `Update _mySP Set Number03 = Number01 + number02`

Comment: check my question above.. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you can use a [**computed field**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.105).aspx) to generate the value from the other two fields.

If you just want to update the table without doing this, you could use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE _myTable SET Number03 = ISNULL(Number01,0) + ISNULL(Number02,0)
```

This will update all rows.

You could update the SP to take a 3rd param:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE _mySP
    (
      @Number01 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
      @Number02 DECIMAL(18, 0) ,
      @IsUpdate BIT = 0
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        IF ( @IsUpdate = 0 )
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO _myTable
                        ( Number01 ,
                          Number02 ,
                          Number03
                        )
                VALUES  ( @Number01 ,
                          @Number02 ,
                          ISNULL(@Number01,0) + ISNULL(@Number02,0)
                        )
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE  _myTable
                SET     Number03 = ISNULL(Number01,0) + ISNULL(Number02,0)
                WHERE Number03 IS NULL
            END
    END
```

**EDIT**: I have added `ISNULL` to the calculation for any numbers that are `null`, it will use **0** instead.

Comment: The Update can change to `...WHERE Number03 IS NULL`, you don't need a cursor though?

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to use the SP to do the work you have to do it one at a time.  Write a cursor to select all the rows with a NULL value and call the SP for each row passing Number01 and Number02.

I suspect your actual example is rather more complicated than the code you've shown.  If you are able to go into more detail we may be able to suggest better approaches.  If it is indeed this simple a computed column or simple update statement would be the way to go.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mark - the OP explicitly states "The question is, how can i execute the storeprocedure without entering the value one by one" and I reply "you cannot."  How is this not an answer to the question?

Comment: And here's me thinking it was about helping people understand and become better programmers, @Mark.  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed columns like this. It will automatically fill all data in ***number03*** column.

```
CREATE TABLE _myTable(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Number01  INT,
Number02  INT,
Number03 AS (Number01 + Number02)
)
```

------OR if you already have table then

```
Alter table _myTable Drop column Number03;
Alter table _myTable Add Number03 AS (Number01 + Number02);
```

-------------***EDITED ACCORDING TO YOUR EDITING  IN QUESTIONS***

You can still put this formula in computed column.
But as you are asking another way, so You can edit your SP like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE _mySP
AS
BEGIN
Update _myTable
set Number03 = ((Number01 + 500) + (POWER(Number02, 2) * 10))
WHERE Number03 is NULL;
END

--------Executing Stored procedure will update table without providing any parameters
Exec _mySP
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(
ID int,
Number1 decimal(18,0),
number2 decimal(18,0),
number3 decimal(18,0))

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES
(1  , 10, 20, 30),
(2  , 5 , 2,  7),
(3  , 4,  4 , 8),
(4  , 10, 1,  NULL),
(5  , 1,  4,  NULL)

UPDATE #Test
Set Number3 = Number1 + number2

SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

Example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc921a/1)